# Python is crashed with "String data, right truncation" while using fast_executemany = True with Sybase Table insert

Tags: python, sybase

I am using the below function to insert Sybase table with high volume data. I am using fast_executemany = True because without this the performance is very slow and not acceptable for my requirement. The below code is giving error for the mentioned table. This is generic function which takes as dataframe and insert to target table passed as input to the function. I can't make table specific customized as table structure varies form one table to other.

### Function

```
def _sybase_insert(source_df, targetTable, loadType, target, database):
    cursor = target.cnxn.cursor()
    sql = 'select top 1 * from ' + targetTable
    cursor.execute(sql)
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    db_types = [d[1] for d in cursor.description]
    print(db_types)
    rows = source_df.values.tolist()
    parms = ("?," * len(rows[0]))[:-1]
    if loadType == 'replace':
        sql = "delete  from " + targetTable
        cursor.execute(sql)
    sql = "INSERT INTO " + targetTable +" VALUES (%s)" % (parms)
    cursor.fast_executemany = True
    cursor.setinputsizes(db_types)
    cursor.executemany(sql, rows)
    cursor.close()
    target.cnxn.commit()
```

**My connection string is**

```
self.cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Adaptive Server Enterprise};uid=' + self.user +';EncryptPassword=1;pwd=' + self.password + ';Port=' + self.dbport + ';Server=' + self.server +';Database=' + dbname)
```

---

Below is the table structure it is failing for with the error `**pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('String data, right truncation: length 22 buffer 20', 'HY000')**`

---

I tried with below as well but did not resolve this issue

```
cursor.setinputsizes(
    [
        (pyodbc.SQL_VARCHAR,500,1000),
        (pyodbc.SQL_INTEGER),
        (pyodbc.SQL_FLOAT),
    ]
)
```

### Target Table

```
COLUMN_NAME      DATA_TYPE TYPE_NAME COLUMN_SIZE BUFFER_LENGTH DECIMAL_DIGITS NUM_PREC_RADIX IS_NULLABLE 
---------------- --------- --------- ----------- ------------- -------------- -------------- ----------- 
Column1          4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
Column2          4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
Column3          4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
Column4          4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
Column5          4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
column6          4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
column7          4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
column8          1         char      12          12            (null)         (null)         NO          
column9          1         char      12          12            (null)         (null)         NO          
column10         4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
column11         4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
column12         1         char      12          12            (null)         (null)         NO          
column13         4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
column14         4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
column15         4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
column16         4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
column17         1         char      30          30            (null)         (null)         NO          
column18         4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
column19         4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
column20         4         int       10          10            0              10             NO          
column21         93        datetime  23          23            3              10             NO          
column22         1         char      10          10            (null)         (null)         NO          
column23         4         int       10          10            0              10             NO
```

Since this is a generic function , kindly let me know what is the issue with the code and why it is  failing for the table I mentioned above.

---

## Actual output with Error

Below is the output with actual error.

```
[<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'datetime.datetime'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ODBCTableCopy.py", line 121, in <module>
    out.append(_table_copy_(targetTable=target_table, sourceObject=sql, source=source, target=target, database=Database , loadType=load_type))
  File "ODBCTableCopy.py", line 67, in _table_copy_
    _sybase_insert(source_df,targetTable, loadType, target, database)
  File "ODBCTableCopy.py", line 47, in _sybase_insert
    cursor.executemany(sql, rows)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('String data, right truncation: length 22 buffer 20', 'HY000')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have got past this in the intervening two years, but for others with the same problem I would look at datatype compatability.  In the example above, the datetime column is a strong contender for being the culprit.

If there is existing data in the target table, query a record, look at the datetime format and ensure that your source data has exactly the same format.  If it doesn't, you need to convert it first.

What I think is happening is that without fast_executemany, implicit type conversion is performed for each row on insert, so it succeeds, slowly.  With fast_executemany, this doesn't happen, which makes it much faster, but can throw errors if the source type does not match what is expected by the target.

Start by taking out date and datetime fields and see if it succeeds.  Then add them back in one by one, checking the format if it fails.

In my case, I was replacing an existing system that inserted 93k rows in around 15 secs.  Without fast_executemany, the new python code took almost 15 minutes to successfully insert the same data.  I switched it to use fast_executemany and it failed.  I had to insert with only the first field, then add the second and keep going until I found the one causing the error.  I could then see that the type didn't match exactly.  Keep going with the remaining fields as there could be more than one!  Once fixed, the insert took under 10 secs.